# linux: dual monitors for presentation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, openoffice

I'd like to setup dual monitors so that one monitor is a projector and the other is my laptop's screen. Then I'd like to show a full screen presentation (openoffice) on the projector and the same presentation but with notes on my laptop.

Comment: And what is the question? There are plenty of tutorials out there for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try openoffice presentation console plugin

Answer (score 1):

The presentation console plugin is now integrated with libreoffice.  Go to the menu: "slide show -> slide show settings -> multiple displays".

Another approach is to export to pdf and then use [PDF Presenter Console](https://pdfpc.github.io).  You won't have animation, but it works pretty well.